# Python | Load list data into a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a way to pass a List variables to class. I am trying below which doesn't seems to be the right way.

```
class data():
    def __init__(self, fname, lname, email):
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname= lname
        self.email = email
data_1 = data('Steve','Harvy','steve.harvy@gmail.com')
print(data_1.fname)
```

This prints `Steve`

However if I try below, it doesn't work.

```
class data():
    def __init__(self, fname, lname, email):
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname= lname
        self.email = email
list = ['Steve','Harvy','steve.harvy@gmail.com']
data_1 = device(list)
print(data_1.fname)
```

Comment: Your example fails with: ***NameError: name 'device' is not defined*** or ***TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'lname' and 'email'***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to unpack the list while passing into the class object, try the below code.

```
class data():
    def __init__(self, fname, lname, email):
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname= lname
        self.email = email

my_list = ['Steve','Harvy','steve.harvy@gmail.com']
#unpack the list using *
data_1 = data(*my_list)
print(data_1.fname)

out[] : Steve
```

#update : read from a txt file list like values

```
with open ("file.txt","r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    mylist = eval(line)
    data_1 = data(*mylist)
    print(data_1.fname)
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. If I want to pass the list from a file, how can I do that.

```
with open ('data.txt', 'r') as data:
    info= data.readlines()
    for line in info:
        data = data(*line)
        print (data.fname)

data.txt

['Steve','Harvy','steve.harvy@gmail.com']
['Michael','Jordan','michael.jordan@gmail.com']

Comment: a file?? file.readlines() and iterate every line, and call the class like in the code...or post a sample data from file and file format

Comment: posted the data above

Comment: same as my_list. Line 1 is person 1 info and line 2 is person 2 info.

Comment: In a list format. Line one ['Steve','Harvy','steve.harvy@gmail.com'] and line 2  ['Michael','Jordan','michael.jordan@gmail.com']

Comment: Updated the answer. Pls test

Comment: It says eval(d) is not defined.

Comment: Okk... Replaced d with line

Comment: Works now. Thank you!